# CSS line break on very long words but not on spaces

Tags: css, line-breaks

Let say I have this paragraph

**iamaverylongwordthathasnospace yehey**

when i use `word-wrap:break-word;` it became

**iamaverylongwordthathas

nospace yehey**

This is good..but when I tried

**iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey**

It became

**iama
verylongwordthathasaspace
yehey**

My question is how to make the paragraph look like this

**iama verylongwordthathas
nospace yehey**

It will wrap on spaces but force to break on long words?

Comment: Define “break long words”. What are “words”, and by which rules should be they broken? This question has been asked often in a vague formulation like this, mostly with wrong answers (or answers that might be partially correct in very special cases).

Comment: @user3204806 did you ever found an answer to this question, It is definitely still unanswered.

Comment: @electronixG - I think you need to explain why "`word-break: break-all;`  is definitely not a good solution". What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `word-break: break-all;`

Here is an example. I put the background as black, so you can see where it breaks: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kDv3/1/)

HTML

```
<div>iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 120px;
    word-break: break-all;
    background: black;
    color: white;  
}
```

Source: [CSS-Tricks: Word-break](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)

Answer (score 3):

Using "word-break: break-all;" (for english or latin-based languages) will break at any character. This means that a very short word (two or three characters long) could break awkwardly depending on the space available. Resize the container (from the bottom right) in the demo below to see the difference between break-all and break-word...

Note: these are CSS only solutions. Javascript would need to be used in order to do more complex things with words and characters.

```css
[draggable=true] {
  cursor: move;
}

.resizable {
  background: #e3e8ee;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  max-width: 360px;
  max-height: 360px;
  min-width: 140px;
  min-height: 360px;
  padding: .5em;
}

.resizable div {
  background: #fff;
  font: 1em/1.1em Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  padding: .25em;
}

.resizable div h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: .1em 0;
}

.break-all span {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.break-word span {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.hyphen span {
  hyphens: auto;
}

.truncate span {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="resizable">
  <div class="break-all" lang="en">
    <h2>Break-all</h2>
    <span>iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey</span>
  </div>
  <div class="break-word" lang="en">
    <h2>Break-word</h2>
    <span>iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey</span>
  </div>
  <div class="break-word hyphen" lang="en">
    <h2>Bk-wd Hyphens</h2>
    <span>iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey</span>
  </div>
  <div class="break-word hyphen truncate" lang="en">
    <h2>Bk-wd Truncate</h2>
    <span>iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit your answer to include the same text `iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey` in the hyphens example. I think this is the closest we'll get to the desired wrapping.

Comment: The last two examples have been updated with text from the original question. However, I think using real words gives a better picture of how the formatting will behave in reality. Here is a fiddle so anyone can edit: https://jsfiddle.net/tkm31reo/7/

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to say please. I requested this because it's easier to compare and see the differences on the same text string.  I believe `word-wrap: break-word; hyphens: auto;` is the best solution available for the question.

Comment: ...and see the fiddle (previous comment) for using real words. I just noticed this question was asked 9 years ago. I am surprised word-wrap and hyphens is as good as it gets w/o using js. At any rate, truncating has gotten better but there is definitely an issue with using hyphens at the same time with line-clamp.

Answer (score 0):

### **behavior of wrapping long words while preserving spaces**

Use the combination of CSS properties to achieve your desiered behaviour:

- **word-break: break-all;** This property enables breaking long words that exceed the container's width. It forces long words to break at any character, even within the word itself, rather than overflowing the container.
- **white-space: pre-wrap;** This property preserves white spaces and allows the text to wrap on spaces. It also respects line breaks in the original text.

### Here's the code for your scenario:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="paragraph-container">
  iama verylongwordthathasaspace yehey
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.paragraph-container {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**Your Output will be:**

iama verylongwordthathas

nospace yehey

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
.your-class-name {
  overflow-wrap: break-word; /* Break long words */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Same as overflow-wrap, for older browsers */
  max-width: some-value; /* Replace with desired container width */
}

<div class="your-class-name">
  iama verylongwordthathasnospace yehey
</div>
```